# How to know if a reindex from remote task is sucessful or failed in elasticsearch using the java high level rest API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I'm using the ElasticSeach highlevel rest api client to do some custom reindexing from another cluster.

```java
    ReindexRequest reindexRequest = new ReindexRequest()
        .setMaxDocs(3000)
        .setDestIndex("my-new-index")
        .setTimeout(TimeValue.timeValueHours(1))
        .setRemoteInfo(
            new RemoteInfo("http", "otherhost", 9200, "/",
                new BytesArray(selectQuery.toString()), "user",
                "password",
                Map.of()), TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(30),
                TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(30)))
        .setSourceIndices("old-index")
        .setScript(new Script(ScriptType.STORED, null, "add_sc_id", Map.of("sc_id", some-id)));

      TaskSubmissionResponse task = esClient.submitReindexTask(reindexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

I periodically check the task to see if it's done or not using the task API

```java
Optional<GetTaskResponse> getTaskResponse =
            esClient.tasks().get(new GetTaskRequest(nodeId, taskId), RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Using this, I can see if the task is completed with `getTaskResponse.get().isCompleted()` but I don't see anyway to check if it's successful or not.

By doing the `GET _taks/nodeId:taskId` with curl, I see there is a `response.failures` field.

Is there a way to retrieve this field with the Java High level rest api client? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: which version of ES ?

Comment: Server is 7.13.2, client is 7.12.1. I also tried with client 7.15.0 with the same result

Comment: I have post code below which deprecated for 7.15 version.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [List Task API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-tasks-list.html).

You can use below Java code for geeting task Failure information:

```
ListTasksRequest request = new ListTasksRequest();
request.setActions("cluster:*"); 
request.setNodes("nodeId1", "nodeId2"); 
request.setParentTaskId(new TaskId("parentTaskId", 42)); 
ListTasksResponse responseTask = client.tasks().list(request,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
List<TaskOperationFailure> taskFailures = response.getTaskFailures();
```